# What does "Remember me to one who lives there" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

We've all heard the song, even if it wasn't from S&G. "Remember me to one who lives there / she was once a true love of mine." But what does that phrase mean? Remember isn't ditransitive; it takes no object. Is this a poetic way to say "remind"?

Comment: "Remember me to X" is a common phrase, at least in the UK, meaning something like "When you next see X, tell them you saw me and I was thinking of them."

Comment: So remember me means remember *to tell her about me*, which is close to remind *her* about me (and my feelings for her).

Comment: See [Lexico/Oxford 1.3](https://www.lexico.com/definition/remember)